# Estimate Cohen's d for effect size

Tags: r, statistics

given two vectors:

```
x <- rnorm(10, 10, 1)
y <- rnorm(10, 5, 5)
```

How to calculate Cohen's d for effect size?

For example, I want to use the [pwr package](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html) to estimate the power of a t-test with unequal variances and it requires Cohen's d.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Following [**this link**](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html) and [**wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_d#Cohen.27s_d), Cohen's d for a t-test seems to be:

[image]

Where `sigma` (denominator) is:

[image]

So, with your data:

```
set.seed(45)                        ## be reproducible 
x <- rnorm(10, 10, 1)                
y <- rnorm(10, 5, 5)

cohens_d <- function(x, y) {
    lx <- length(x)- 1
    ly <- length(y)- 1
    md  <- abs(mean(x) - mean(y))        ## mean difference (numerator)
    csd <- lx * var(x) + ly * var(y)
    csd <- csd/(lx + ly)
    csd <- sqrt(csd)                     ## common sd computation

    cd  <- md/csd                        ## cohen's d
}
> res <- cohens_d(x, y)
> res
# [1] 0.5199662
```

Answer (score 29):

There are several packages providing a function for computing Cohen's d. You can for example use the `cohensD` function form the `lsr` package :

```
library(lsr)
set.seed(45)
x <- rnorm(10, 10, 1)
y <- rnorm(10, 5, 5)
cohensD(x,y)
# [1] 0.5199662
```

Comment: could you set seed to say 45 and compute it again and paste the result? (for reproducibility)

Comment: Other packages that contain a Cohen's function are: _effsize_ and _pwr_ (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the [effsize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effsize/effsize.pdf) package.

```
library(effsize) 
set.seed(45) x <- rnorm(10, 10, 1) 
y <- rnorm(10, 5, 5) 
cohen.d(x,y)
# Cohen's d
# d estimate: 0.5199662 (medium)
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#        inf        sup 
# -0.4353393  1.4752717
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, more recent option is to use `effectsize`, which is very flexible and also returns confidence intervals:
https://easystats.github.io/effectsize/reference/cohens_d.html

```r
library(effectsize)

x <- rnorm(10, 10, 1)
y <- rnorm(10, 5, 5)

# for independent measures design
cohens_d(x, y)
#> Cohen's d |        95% CI
#> -------------------------
#> 0.77      | [-0.15, 1.67]
#> 
#> - Estimated using pooled SD.

# in case design is paired
cohens_d(x, y, paired = TRUE)
#> Cohen's d |        95% CI
#> -------------------------
#> 0.49      | [-0.19, 1.20]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>