# Why am I getting a different cohen's D using the formula and using a function in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm comparing `X` (a 2 category variable) and `Y` (let's say age). First, I did a `t.test(Y~X)`, which returned

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Y by X
t = 1.0579, df = 680.889, p-value = 0.2905
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.101452  3.674986
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       47.07576        45.78899
```

Next, I used the `cohensD(X, Y)` function from the package `lsr`. It returned 4.017.

To check that I used a Cohen's D calculator, which uses the equation `Cohen's D = 2t/sqrt(df) = 1.0579*2/sqrt(680.889) = .081`.

Why am I getting .081 using the formula and 4.017 using `lsr`?

Comment: This might be a good reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436702/estimate-cohens-d-for-effect-size

Comment: Ya, I saw that and I don't know how they got that equation for Cohen's D, while this other site had teh one I put above (http://www.uccs.edu/~lbecker/#Calculate%20d%20and%20r%20using%20t%20alues%20%28sepparate%20groups%29)

Comment: You may be misusing the uccs formula; also are you certain you've got fully independent inputs?  If you've got a nonzero $\delta_x*\delta_y$ then the d-test will require more work.

Comment: I'm not sure. All that I know is what I have above. If you put the t value and df from the output in my OP into the link, then you will get the values I found. So I don't think I am using the uccs formula incorrectly. 

I found this: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsr/lsr.pdf

On page 9, it tells you about the different ways to find Cohen D. Maybe I'm not doing it the right way? If you know statistics, which of those methods is the one the uccs site refers to? Thanks

Comment: This is quite similar to the frequently asked question: "Why is this "chi-square test" different than the one I made in SAS?" It generally requires more specifics about the actual statisical question being asked. There must be a hundred different "chi-square tests".